# Disable UIBarButtonItem when popover is dismissed

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I am new in iOS development and I am trying to show a popover when tap a barButtomItem. So far I have this:

```
-(IBAction)shareButtonPressed :(id)sender{    
    UIViewController *popoverViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ShareOptionsViewController" bundle:nil];
    popoverViewController.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(319, 422);

    self.popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:popoverViewController];
    [self.popoverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny  animated:NO];
}
```

This code works and when I tap the correct button, the popover is showed. The problem is when the popOver is showed, if I tap again the button, the app crashes. I know is because it is trying to alloc a variable that is already created. I think the solution should be disable the button when the popover loads but I don't know how to activate again once the popover is dismissed.

Am I right? How can I enable the button when the popOver is dismissed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should disabled the button in your shareButtonPressed method.

```
-(IBAction)shareButtonPressed :(id)sender{    
UIViewController *popoverViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ShareOptionsViewController" bundle:nil];
popoverViewController.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(319, 422);

self.popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:popoverViewController];
[self.myButton setEnabled:NO];
[self.popoverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny  animated:NO];
}
```

Then you make your view controller comply with the UIPopoverControllerDelegate protocol. After that you implement the popoverControllerDidDismissPopover method.

```
-(void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController
{
if (!self.myButton.enabled) // Just to make sure the button is disabled.
    [self.myButton setEnabled:YES];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check if instance is already created.

```
-(IBAction)shareButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    if (self.popoverController == nil) {
        self.popoverController = alloc/init...;
        [_popoverController present...];
    } else {
        if (self.popoverController.popoverVisible)
            [self.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
        self.popoverController = nil;
    }
}
```

There is a possibility, it will be garbage collected before animation completes, yielding invalid user experience. Then, if possible, I would pre-create the instance in viewDidLoad or contructor or so and then just present and dismiss as needed, checking visible property.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this "event --> responsible" list:

1) Button pressed --> MainViewController - IBAction

2) Popover shown --> MainViewController - IBAction

3) Button disabled --> MainViewController - IBAction

4) Popover dissmis --> popoverDelegate - popoverControllerDidDismissPopover

5) Button enabled --> popoverDelegate - popoverControllerDidDismissPopover

So, if the delegate of your popover is the MainViewController, you would have access to the button, if it is a different class you'll probably have to set up a protocol in order to enable the button back.

Tell me if you need any further explanations...

Answer (score 0):

you can detect if the popover is shown and dismissed:

```
- (IBAction)shareButtonPressed :(id)sender{
    if (self.popoverController) {
        [self.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
        self.popoverController = nil;
    } else {
        UIViewController *popoverViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ShareOptionsViewController" bundle:nil];
        popoverViewController.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(319, 422);

        self.popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:popoverViewController];
        [self.popoverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny  animated:NO];
    }
}
```

or if you just want to disable the button:

```
- (IBAction)shareButtonPressed :(id)sender{
    ...
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    button.enabled = NO;
}
```

but in this case you will have to detect when the user close the `popOver` to enable the button again. You can do this adopting the `UIPopoverController` delegate ([see documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverControllerDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html)) in your class

Answer (score 0):

Just modify your code like this...

```
-(IBAction)shareButtonPressed :(id)sender{    
        UIViewController *popoverViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ShareOptionsViewController" bundle:nil];
        popoverViewController.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(319, 422);

         if(self.popoverController)
          {
            [self.popovercontroller dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
            self.popovercontroller = nil;
           }   
        self.popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:popoverViewController];
        [self.popoverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny  animated:NO];
    }
```